# Single dll for Windows 8 and Windows 8.1

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, dll, windows-store-apps

I've created a class library project (dll) for Windows 8 Store Apps in VS 2012 but now introduction of Windows 8.1 there are some new API's available for the OS(e.g advertising ID to uniquely identify a user) which I want to use in my dll but I don't want to release a separate dll targeting Windows 8.1. My aim is to distribute a single dll which can be referenced both in Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 store apps. If I will create a dll targeted to 8.1 then 8.0 apps will not be able to use my dll.

Is there any way to check a specific Api available at runtime or any preprocessor for Windows 8.1 apps so that my dll recognize the OS at runtime and execute the code e.g

```
string deviceId=string.Empty;

#if W8.1
deviceId=Windows.System.UserProfile.AdvertisingManager.AdvertisingId;
#endif
```

Or please suggest any other way so that I can distribute only one dll to my users?

Comment: You can possibly use the [version helper APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn424972%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: You can do it by reflection, assuming you're allowed reflection in Windows apps? (but I can't see why not) to access the class and property by name

Comment: I'm trying to find the API availability using Type but `Type tp = Type.GetType("Windows.System.UserProfile.AdvertisingManager");` returns null. but when I use `Type tp1 = typeof(Windows.System.UserProfile.AdvertisingManager);` its returning me class but it will give me compile error in VS2012 as this api is not available

Comment: I was committing the mistake. `Type.GetType` needs fully qualified name. correct code is:
`Type tp = Type.GetType("Windows.System.UserProfile.AdvertisingManager, Windows.System, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime");
            if (tp != null)
            {
                PropertyInfo properties = tp.GetRuntimeProperty("AdvertisingId");
                if (properties != null)
                {
                    string deviceId = (string)properties.GetValue(null);
                }
            } `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally doing it by reflection. AdvertisingManager API is not available in Windows 8 but if the an app is running on Windows 8.1, same dll(targeted framework is Windows 8) will get access to AdvertisingManager through reflection. So, no need to distribute two dll's for different versions.

```
      Type tp = Type.GetType("Windows.System.UserProfile.AdvertisingManager, Windows.System, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime");
        if (tp != null)
        {
            PropertyInfo properties = tp.GetRuntimeProperty("AdvertisingId");
            if (properties != null)
            {
                string deviceId = (string)properties.GetValue(null);
            }
        }
```

**Output**

> Case 1:  Windows 8 app running on Windows 8

In this case, tp will return null as the AdvertisingManager API is not available in Windows 8.

> Case 2:  Windows 8 app running on Windows 8.1

As AdvertisingManager API is available in Windows 8.1, all apps targeted to Windows 8 will can access to this API and will get the AdvertisingId in this case.

> Case 3:  Windows 8.1 app running on Windows 8.1

The API is available directly in Windows 8.1 apps. So, no need to go by reflection path.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by creating own conditional directives based on .NET framework version. Windows 8.1 uses .NET 4.5.1

This MSDN sample may help you => [Building Multiple TargetFramework Version Libraries](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Building-Multiple-47aa2667)

Comment: I think that sets the target framework at compile time, though, which isn't what he wants.